# Инициализация нового хоста ansible: как проверить возможность подключения к хосту

Tags: ansible

У меня используется ansible 2.0

Есть скрипты, которые выполняют различные настройки серверов, общие части вынесены в роли и т.п. Настройка выполняется на каждом сервере из-под учётной записи automate_ansible, который может passwordless sudo: в ansible_config прописан remote_user, все скрипты имеют строку become -- в общем, всё давно работает.

Всё хорошо, кроме того, что нужно первоначально этого пользователя создать. Есть как раз один скрипт, который коннектится к серверу как root, создаёт пользователя ansbile, делает некоторые настройки по корпоративным стандартам.

Боль-печаль заключается в том, что этот скрипт -- единственный неидемпонентный: среди его шагов есть один шаг, в котором устанавливается запрет подключения по ssh пользователем root и поэтому как только выполнишь скрипт -- уже работают все остальные, но этот уже вылетит с ошибкой подключения к серверу.

А очень хочется иметь возможность запускать этот скрипт ещё раз, чтобы ансибл перезаписал заново пароли рута, те же самые конфиги ssh, пользователей и т.п.

Есть ли возможность как-то проверять предварительно соединение с сервером (ткнуться поду учёткой спец. пользователя, если есть -- пройти весь остаток скрипта из-под него, только с become, если нет -- зайти root'ом и остаток скрипта пройти как чистый рут)?

Все варианты решения, которые я знаю - это лишь костыли.

Либо можно написать крошечный скрипт инициализации, который выполнит всего одно действие (создаст пользователя для анисибл и отвалится) -- а все остальные действия вынести в скрипт инициализация2.

Либо можно оставить длинный скрипт инициализации -- и отдельно писать практически такой же скрипт на повтор инициализации, но уже от пользователя ансибл.

Хочется возможности тестирования соединения ssh. Это реально сделать или не предусмотрено? Кто и как решает подобную задачу? Или может и нет большого смысла в том, чтобы пытаться её решить?

Comment: Первая идея: в начале плейбука проверить наличие спецпользователя, по результатам записать в переменную нужного пользователя,  что-то вроде `administration_user=root`, потом на каждом плее задавать пользователя через `remote_user: "{{ administration_user }}"`

Comment: Вот это может быть вам интересно: https://github.com/gravitational/teleport

Answer (score 2):

На днях на большом stackoverflow было обсуждение [этой же темы](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39175623/what-are-the-best-practices-for-locking-down-ssh-with-ansible) (там только порт ssh перевешивается на нестандартный), видимо нужно признать, что наиболее употребимый подход -- это вынесение в отдельный плейбук инициализации шагов по настройке.

Получается, что каждый скрипт остаётся идемпонентным.

Кто-то старается побольше всего вместить в такие плейбуки, кто-то меньше -- но направление в целом одинаковое.